# Why the second bullet point in §12.2/5 is considered an exception to the rule explicited in this paragraph?

Tags: c++, c++11, reference, language-lawyer

§12.2/5 (my emphasis)

> The second context is when a reference is bound to a temporary. The temporary to which the reference is
>   bound or the temporary that is the complete object of a subobject to which the reference is bound persists for the lifetime of the reference **except**:
>
> - A temporary bound to a reference ...
> - A temporary bound to a reference parameter in a function call (5.2.2) persists until the completion of the full-expression containing the call.

In the snippet below ([live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/19b2fe60720d31bf)) one can see that the temporary `A()` is bound to the reference `a` for the lifetime of the reference, that is, the destructor `~A()` is invoked at the end of the function `f`.

```
#include <iostream>

struct A{
    A() { std::cout << "A()" << '\n'; }
    ~A() { std::cout << "~A()" << '\n'; }
};

void f(A&& a) { std::cout << "f()" << '\n'; }

int main()
{
    f(A());
}
```

Comment: In your example, the function call is the full-expression, so your example doesn't really demonstrate anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider this absurd example:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {
    void bar() { std::cout << "bar [" << i << "]" << std::endl; }
    ~A() { std::cout << "dtor" << std::endl; }

    int i;
};

A& foo(A&& a) { return a; }

int main()
{
    foo(A{4}).bar();
}
```

If the lifetime of the temporary wasn't extended to the completion of the full-expression, `.bar()` would be called on an already-destroyed object, since the lifetime of `a` ends when `foo` is complete. As is, this will print:

```
bar [4]
dtor
```